# What is the best solution to get rid from login looping in ubuntu?

Tags: partitioning, login

I have found many people asking for help about login looping issue of ubuntu.One thing i wand to insure is that there is no single particular reason which may result in login looping so there is no single solution to this.But,there is only one solution why works for all and that is reinstalling ubuntu.Well, what is about the data i had in,how can i save it? The answer is we can reinstall it without loosing data of home/ directory.for this,while partitioning,we can use home partition of old installation in new installation without formation it.Other partitions (swap,root,efi) need to be created again.so we can free up these partitions mentioned to create again for new installation.

Comment: So what is the question? There is no universal reason of this problem, so there is no universal solution. People break the system using different ways and solutions may be different. Reinstalling helps, we can't argue about it ;-) But it is not a solution.

Comment: The only ever reason I've had a login loop has been because $HOME has become filled, and there is insufficient space to allow GUI login (text logins still work).  Other reasons all relate to something the user (me) did in the prior session, which means the issue would be expected.   Yes you can re-install without loosing data in $HOME, even change releases (ie. upgrade via re-install without impacting $HOME) however backups should always be performed as errors can be made.

Comment: What I have told is solution to use your system again normally when you have found no other solution.

Comment: But i had it for different reason.